# get Values from NSMutableDictionary in swift?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I have a stored `NSMutableDictionary` in `NSUSerDefaluts` and i have retrieve that successfully.

```
if var tempFeed: NSDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("selectedFeeds") {
       println("selected Feed: \(tempFeed)")
        savedDictionary = tempFeed.mutableCopy() as NSMutableDictionary
```

The Question is How can i convert that MutableDictionary into an array/MuatableArray and iterate it so i can get the values of it.Here is the Dictionary. i want to get the values for all URL in that.

```
{
4 =     {
    URL = "myurl1";
};
5 =     {
    URL = "myurl3";
};
6 =     {
    URL = "myurl3";
};
}
```

I have tried number of options with failure.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add all the urls into an array, iterate over it and add append all values to some array.

```
for (_,urlDict) in savedDictionary {
  for(_,url) in urlDict {
    urlArr.append(url) // create empty urlArr before
  }
}
```

urlArr now contains all the urls (not ordered)

Comment: This is what i have done.Thanks. I have also tried the answers @Airspped Velocity and @Christian but it gives en error like `NSDictionary does not have mebmer named Value`. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Glad it helped, but Airspeed's answer enumerates all the possibilities that you have, and you can choose any.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.values.array` on your dictionary to get the values unordered. 
 as an array
Then, you can just add your `NSArray` to your `NSMutableArray`.

```
var mutableArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: savedDictionary .values.array)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is iterate over it, you don’t have to convert it to an array.  You can do that directly:

```
for (key,value) in savedDictionary {
    println("\(key) = \(value)")
}
```

(if you’re not interested in the key at all, you can replace that variable name with `_` to ignore it).

Alternatively, instead of making `tempFeed` of type `NSDictionary`, just leave it as the type `dictionaryForKey` returns, which is a Swift dictionary.  This has a `.values` property, which is a lazy sequence of all the values in the dictionary.  You can convert that to an array (so `tempFeed.values.array`) or perform operations on it directly (use it in `for…in`, map it such as `tempFeeds.values.map { NSURL(string: toString($0)) }` etc.)